# OWA add-in on iOS

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

I have difficulties with getting owa add-in to work on iOS devices. 
It does not appear at all.
I also checked whether it works, using [sample](https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo), but in fact it did not work.

However I installed evernote, and add-in is shown there.

I would be glad if someone could help me with it or gave me direction where to look.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My guess (and based on some experimentation) is that only add-ins installed via the office store will appear. I've yet to push an add-in thru the store to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

First step you need to add to your manifest some information that you support this devices :

```
 <DesktopSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AppRead/Home.html"/>
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </DesktopSettings>
  <TabletSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AppRead/Home.html" />
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </TabletSettings>
  <PhoneSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/AppRead/Home.html" />
  </PhoneSettings>
```

Second step is to install your manifest manually from OWA like in this [tutorial](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing)

Then you could see your add in both from OWA application and from your browser of your device.

Good luck